# Is it possible to create variables dynamically into an array that points to a fixed variable

Tags: php

Is it possible to create variables dynamically into an array that points to a fixed variable

For example:

```
  $EUR_EUR = 1;
  $EUR_USD = 2;
  $EUR_AUD = 3; 

  $EUR = "EUR_";


  $result = "$" . '' . $EUR . '' . $get_value;
  $array[] = $result;
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => $EUR_EUR [1] => $EUR_USD [2] => $EUR_AUD )
```

Now i need those values in the array to be pointed to the variables, as i understand it is only strings at the moment and not pointing the variables. There is more to the code where it runs through a foreach loop to get the "$get_value".

Comment: What's wrong with simply having an **array**, $array['EUR']['EUR'] = 1; and then have whatever dynamic value you want? $result = $array[$EUR][$get_value]

Answer (score -1):

I would not recommend to do this, but you can store references to the variables in the array.

```
$EUR_EUR = 1;

$array['EUR'] = &$EUR_EUR;
```

When you now change the value of the array, you also change the variable referenced to.

```
$array['EUR'] = 77;
```

```
var_dump($array);

// array changed

array(1) {
  'EUR' =>
  int(77)
}

var_dump($EUR_EUR);

// as well as the referenced variable

int(77)
```